maven-deploy-plugin: deploy only jar file without pom file
In my project - which is Spring Boot app built using maven - I updated from maven 3.6.3 to 3.9.6. This introduced one change in the deploying phase: with the old version the command below deployed only the jar file to nexus, without pom.xml - this is the behavior I want to keep with newer maven version. The newer version deploys both the jar and pom files.
mvn deploy:deploy-file 
    -DgroupId=com.example 
    -DartifactId=example-artifact
    -Dversion=1.2.3 
    -DgeneratePom=false
    -Dpackaging=jar 
    -DrepositoryId=nexus 
    -Durl=https://my-nexus-address.com/nexus/repository/my-maven-releases 
    -Dfile=example-artifact/target/example-artifact-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar

With the new maven I can enforce the old behavior by specifying the older version of maven-deploy-plugin like this:
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file 
    -DgroupId=com.example 
    -DartifactId=example-artifact
    -Dversion=1.2.3 
    -DgeneratePom=false
    -Dpackaging=jar 
    -DrepositoryId=nexus 
    -Durl=https://my-nexus-address.com/nexus/repository/my-maven-releases 
    -Dfile=example-artifact/target/example-artifact-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I checked that maven-deploy-plugin version 3.0.0 and newer deploy both jar and pom files.
I thought that -DgeneratePom=false parameter will make the pom.xml to be not deployed to nexus (I checked maven-deploy-plugin documentation for that) but it looks the behavior changed between plugin versions 2.8.2 and 3.0.0 and newer.
UPDATE:
when calling the first command with "mvn -X" to have debug logs I can see that the pom.xml file is taken from the jar itself:
[DEBUG] Using META-INF/maven/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/pom.xml as pomFile

If I manually edit the jar-with-dependencies.jar and delete MATA-INF/maven directory then only the jar file is deployed to nexus, without pom.xml. But I'm not sure if deleting the META-INF/maven is a good idea and if it possible do make maven build the jar file without that subdirectory.
END OF UPDATE
Question: how can I keep the latest maven version 3.9.6 with the latest maven-deploy-plugin in my project and make the deploy command only deploy the jar file without deploying the pom.xml along with it.

As Maven follows a convention-over-configuration policy, you probably should not try to outsmart the plugins behaviours. But you can use different plugins, maybe the Wagon Maven Plugin could help you to transfer files to a server.
